# How to extract the Month Name from SharePoint Column using REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

1. I am having the Single Line Text Column (OurTrainingSession) where it is 
   storing the date values in the format of MM/DD/YYYY (12/30/2018) . Along 
   with some string values like "Completed" , "Successful" ,"Upcoming".etc
2. Now I would like to extract only the month number using REST .

Can any one please help me how can I make it

Comment: Check this link out from StackExchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date

Comment: You should really separate these out.  Even if you put code in, you will not be able to force users to put the date in exactly like you want it each time because you have other string values that will make validation extreemly difficult or impossible.  Separate your date from your status fields.  That is just proper form building as well.